# Am I misunderstanding when componentDidMount is triggered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I am trying to render information received via an API call in my componentDidMount. This works as expected, however, I am under the assumptions that by the time I render my react component, the componentDidMount would have been called already. This seems to not be the case as when I try to access the data in my react element, it is undefined, and I can see that it logs to the console before the component is mounted. Am I doing this wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

class App2 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = { projectData: [] };
    this.state = { value: '' }
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    alert("A update was submitted:" + JSON.stringify({ update: this.state.value }));
    fetch("/put", {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ update: this.state.value }),
    }).then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => alert('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
      .catch(error => console.log('Error:', error));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount');
    fetch("/api")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          // console.log('Result: ', result);
          this.setState({
            projectData: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.setState({
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    const { error, projectData } = this.state;

    console.log(projectData);

    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS"
            crossorigin="anonymous" />
          <h1>Project Data:</h1>
          {/* <ul>
            {projectData.map((number) =>
              <ListItem key={number.toString()}
                value={number} />
            )}
          </ul> */}

          <Form id="formName" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>Update an item:</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter update" id="update" name="update" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form>

        </div>
      );
  }
}

export default App2;
```

Comment: Where or When...? Here is the flow: `render` -> `componentWillMount` -> `component mounts on DOM(not a lifecycle method)` -> `componentDidMount`. As the name suggests, its meant to be triggered after the component is rendered for the first time. This is to unblock renderring of  component

Comment: Okay, that's what I suspected but my tutor told me otherwise. Then how would I go about to do this specific problem, because the API call will happen after the render, each time resulting in the render trying to access a undefined state?

Comment: You would check if the data is there and if not you show a loading spinner or return null.
`if (this.state.data) return null else
return (...jsx)`

Comment: Thanks guys. I am still new to this, appreciate the help!